# How to add offset or delay to audio file with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, offset, converters

I need offset (some silence) in the start of file, so I tried:

```
./ffmpeg -itsoffset 100 -i 3.mp3 offset_test.mp3
```

But it doesn't work.

How to add offset to audio file with ffmpeg?

Comment: Try concatenating silence instead.

Comment: Doesn't offset work with audio at all?

Comment: `itsoffset` is for adjusting timestamps... that's not at all what you actually want to do.  You want to **add some silence to the start of your file**, and therefore you need to **concatenate silence with your audio**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For formats without timestamps, you'll need to add silence, as @Brad mentioned.

```
ffmpeg -i 3.mp3 -af adelay=100000|100000 delayed.mp3
```

The adelay takes delay in milliseconds per channel, separated by `|`.

Comment: Thanks, adelay is exactly what I need.

Comment: It works in command: `ffmpeg -vn -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3  -filter_complex "[a]adelay=2000|2000[a];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:dropout_transition=0" -q:a 1 -acodec libmp3lame -y amix_test.mp3`, but when I try `ffmpeg -i 3.mp3 -af adelay=100000|100000 delayed.mp3` it says `At least one output file must be specified` maybe you can say how specify output?

Comment: If you're on windows, you'll need to enclose the adelay string  in quotes.

Comment: What if, instead, of delay, we want to remove time (bring it forward) from the audio?

Comment: You would use the atrim filter. Or simply use `ffmpeg -ss X -i 3.mp3 -c copy trimmed.mp3` where X is the duration in seconds of leading content to be trimmed.

Comment: Hi Gyan, thanks for your reply. I was hoping that if there is some single filter that could handle the positive delay (add delay to audio) or negative delay (remove time from the audio). Like the -itsoffset filter. Do you know if -itsoffset could be used only for audio files? https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/correcting-for-audiovideo-sync-issues-with-the-ffmpeg-programs-itsoffset-switch/

Comment: itsoffset is relevant only when combining with other audio or video streams - not for solitary audio-only files like a `.mp3`

Comment: It extends audio to 10 times of original length. Here's my command `ffmpeg -i output-audio.aac -af "adelay=58000|58000" output2-audio.aac`

Comment: @Richardd I had to mix a video file without audio, with another audio file. The audio file was a bit in advance, trimming the video file by 0.5 second did the trick !
`$ ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -i silent_video.mp4 -i audio.flac -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental synchronized_video_with_sound.mp4`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found so far for ffmpeg ver > 4.2:

```
ffmpeg -i audio_in.wav -af areverse,apad=pad_dur=1s,areverse audio_out.wav
```

This will add an offset of 1 second to the audio.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way for -itsoffset should be:

```
ffmpeg -i audiofile.mp3 -itsoffset 100 offsetted.mp3
```

however, I'm not sure if -itsoffset will work.

Comment: Not true! `itsoffset` is an input option and as such need to precede the input file.  See [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html): "As a general rule, options are applied to the next specified file. Therefore, order is important, and you can have the same option on the command line multiple times. Each occurrence is then applied to the next input or output file."